# Next Key of 2d Array using next()

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array:

```
$arrQuestionsAnswers = ([10] => Array ([0] => 'Male'), [4] => Array ([0] => 08-29-1975))
```

If I'm on the first element [10], how do I show the next key [4]?

I've tried using `next()`, but that simply returns `([0] => 08-29-1975)`, but I want to return `([4] =>  [0] => 08-29-1975)`

```
$arrNextQuestion = next($arrQuestionsAnswers);
```

returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 08-29-1975 )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: show us the script you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [key](http://php.net/key) with next.

```
$array = array(10=>234, 20=>array());

reset($array);
echo key($array);// 10
next($array);
echo $key = key($array);// 20

var_dump(array($key => $array[$key]));
```